# SQL Query to return records in excess of allowed amount within range

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

Imagine a worker is allowed to have a variable amount of shifts in a defined time period. We want to query for shifts in excess of the allowed amount for any period as well as shifts outside of all periods.

I've linked db-fiddle with test query. The issues here are:

1. For excess shifts, the order of the joined shifts is non-deterministic. I only want to see the excess Shift (2016-05-30 is the 4th shift in a period where only 3 shifts have been authorized).
2. I also want to see the 3 shifts that have not been authorized at all (2019-04-25, 2019-06-02, 2019-06-04).

I expect I need to flip the query around (i.e. select from Shift join Authorization) and use some combination of group by, order by, and limit, but I haven't had any success. Any input would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `Authorization` (
  `AuthorizationId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WorkerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Start` date NOT NULL,
  `End` date NOT NULL,
  `ShiftsAllowed` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AuthorizationId`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Shift` (
  `ShiftId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WorkerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Date_` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ShiftId`)
);

INSERT INTO Authorization (WorkerId,Start,End,ShiftsAllowed) VALUES 
(1,'2019-05-01','2019-05-15',2),
(1,'2019-05-16','2019-05-31',3);

INSERT INTO Shift (WorkerId,Date_) VALUES 
(1,'2019-04-25'),
(1,'2019-05-01'),
(1,'2019-05-10'),
(1,'2019-05-16'),
(1,'2019-05-20'),
(1,'2019-05-25'),
(1,'2019-05-30'),
(1,'2019-06-02'),
(1,'2019-06-04');
```

```
select 
    Authorization.Start, 
    Authorization.End, 
    Authorization.ShiftsAllowed, 
    count(Shift.Date_), 
    group_concat(Shift.Date_),
    reverse(
      substring_index(
        reverse(group_concat(Shift.Date_)),
        ',',
        count(Shift.Date_) - Authorization.ShiftsAllowed
      )
    )
from Authorization
left join Shift
on
    Shift.WorkerId = Authorization.WorkerId
    and Shift.Date_ between Authorization.Start and Authorization.End
group by Authorization.AuthorizationId
having 
count(Shift.ShiftId) > Authorization.ShiftsAllowed
```

[View on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vPrbBicSwwgoA2tGLVafKs/2)

Comment: Learn to use proper `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Eric Would you mind describing or showing an example?

Comment: `Authorization.Start`, `Authorization.End`, `Authorization.ShiftsAllowed` are all non-aggregated columns, and must be included in `GROUP BY`.  No other dbms system will run your code.  Even newer version of `MySQL` will not run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.7 does not support the window function.

I used the correlated subquery instead of it.

Try this:

```
select a3.shiftid, a3.workerid, a3.date_ from (
select a2.*, 
(select count(*) 
 from (select s.*, a.start, a.end, a.shiftsallowed
        from Shift s
        left join Authorization a
        on a.workerid = s.workerid
        and s.date_ between a.start and a.end) a1 
        where a1.date_ <= a2.date_ 
        and a1.workerid = a2.workerid and a1.start = a2.start and a1.end  = a2.end) rnk
from (
select s.*, a.start, a.end, a.shiftsallowed
from Shift s
left join Authorization a
on a.workerid = s.workerid
and s.date_ between a.start and a.end )a2)a3
where a3.rnk > a3.shiftsallowed or rnk = 0
```

I suggest you run this query if you do not understand the answer.

```
select s.*, a.start, a.end, a.shiftsallowed
from Shift s
left join Authorization a
on a.workerid = s.workerid
and s.date_ between a.start and a.end
```

Then add the rank column -- correlated subquery

Test Result:

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vPrbBicSwwgoA2tGLVafKs/6)

Answer (score 0):

Well done for providing an MCVE.

For versions older than 8.0...

```
SELECT workerid
     , date_   FROM 
     ( SELECT s.workerid
            , a.authorizationid
            , a.start
            , a.end
            , a.shiftsallowed
            , s.date_
            , CASE WHEN @prev = authorizationid THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:=authorizationid prev 
         FROM shift s 
         LEFT
         JOIN authorization a 
           ON a.workerid = s.workerid 
          AND s.date_ BETWEEN a.start AND a.end 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY a.authorizationid
            , s.date_
     ) x  WHERE i>shiftsallowed OR authorizationid IS NULL;
```